# Google Drive mount problem

Tags: 22.04, google-drive

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. I have Google account added and see Google Drive as a external disk. But when I try to mount it I get "timed out".

It worked fine before. I believe the problem has begun after I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.

Is it possible to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar issue as well though mine only becomes inaccessible intermittently. Definitely an issue with 22.04 as even when it's working saving to the drive from firefox has become buggy and often freezes.

Best I can suggest is back up files are revert to 20.04 which is better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In Settings > Online Accounts go to Google and log in to your Google Account following the instructions on screen.

After the validation process has been completed, open Nautilus and you will find you google-drive account listed in the left panel.

Clicking on that gives you access to your files in Google Drive without needing to mount the drive further.

If, as part of the upgrade process, something didn't quite go right, follow the above instructions to reset it in 22.04.

Comment: I've logged off and then logged in to Google account already. But it didn't help

Comment: try Remove Account and reinstall  - did you try that?

Comment: Reinstall what? Ubuntu? I afraid that's not an option. There are too much apps and data to make it happen. I hope there is a way to fix the problem

Comment: Not Ubuntu, no... go to *Settings > Online Accounts* click on *Google Account* before *Add an account*  then select *Remove Account* in the red box at the bottom of the window. Then add it again from scratch.

Comment: That's what I've already done. Nothing has changed. Also I see nothing in `journalctl`. So I've no idea where to see the diagnostics